# Jetbrains Rider, Xamarin IOS No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, jetbrains-ide, rider

I try to deploy my Xamarin IOS App to my Iphone. Working with Jetbrains Rider.

I receive this Build Error:

Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(693, 3): No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.

I tried to open the IOS project from Rider in XCode, that works but I can not run it there, get some other warnings because some Icons are missing.. 
And also several Errors.

Are you able to deploy your App from Rider to your Iphone?

edit:

[XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvTyj.png)

[Rider_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol11P.png)

[Rider_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc2Fp.png)

Comment: And when you try the same in Visual Studio? Did you add your account in Xcode and download the provisioning profiles and create a developer certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You can not just open .NET application in xCode and run it. It does not work in that way.

When you open project in xCode from Rider (and VS4Mac also) IDE generates an xCode project with obj-c stubs based on your .NET project structure to allow you use xCode interface/plist designers.

So in your case probably you have to create and use personal developer certificate. To do that:

1. Open you project in xCode
2. Go to project properties, 'Signing & Capabilities' tab
3. Enable 'Automatically manage signing'
4. Choose personal team (with your name).

[image: Sample]

After that provisioning profile and Signing certificate should be generated and installed automatically.

Return to Rider and ensure `CFBundleIdentifier` in `info.plist` file is equal to Bundle Identifier from XCode project: `com.xtmq.App4` in my case.

See related issue in JetBrains issue tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-23621

Comment: Thank you, tried it out, dit everything the same like on your screenshot also set the bundle identifier in info.plist but still geht the same error. thx for the link.

Comment: Probably you have to try to run an application from XCode (sample swift app for example) Probably something wrong with your device.

Comment: But there are no special thing with my Iphone? are there a "special" settin? I can run Swift apps from Xcode, also I can use the Simulator from Rider.

Comment: If you can run swift apps from Xcode everything should be OK in Rider also. Could you go to project properties (from the Solution Explorer), go to your active configuration (Debug\iPhone or so) and check if Rider detect your provision profile.

Comment: Hmm it is set to automatic, I can choose mine but it also generates me the error.. I added pictures with my settings, but there is nothing wrong  ?!

Comment: Also I do not need to be part of the developer program right? I did all with my normal AppleID

Comment: As far as I know you should not be part of the developer program. Actually right now I have no idea what is wrong...

Comment: Ok, thank you so far. At the moment I can not create new keys because they are limited 7 in 7 days  I will wait and try it again in a week.

Comment: This definitely fixed my error in our project

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7171).

I had to go to the .csproj file in my IOS project and set the

CodesignKey: Apple Development: xxxx (5Pxxxxxxxx)

the default value was "iPhone Developer"
After that I still get a warning because the signing key is wrong and I have to choose an other on. I can klick Run anyway and Run the App on my IPhone.

(I also did the XCode project with the bundle identifier)