# DVTDeveloperModeHelper not found why trying to deploy to a physical iOS device from Rider

Tags: android, ios, macos, maui, rider

I am developing a mobile app, targeting iOS and Android, I started developing it over in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows but have moved over to MacOS, due to having issues with the iOS simulator not working on Windows.

On the Mac (Ventura 13.0) I have XCode 14.1 installed, Visual Studio For Mac 17.3.8 and Jetbrains Rider 2022.2.3. I am trying to use Rider as its the most consistent experience for me on mac as I usually live in it over on Windows.

I have developed the app to a point where I want to test it on physical devices, it deploys and runs without issue on both platform's simulators (on MacOS via Rider), and is the same for deploying and running on my Android device. The problem has arisen when trying to deploy it to a physical iPhone 14 (16.1), I have the device selected in the deploy target dropdown and it builds ok, but when it tries to deploy the app to the device I get the below error. I have checked and that framework is not in XCode and I don't know where to get it, if that is the real issue.

The application builds and deploys from Visual Studio for Mac to the iOS device without issue, the same cannot be said for Android, and to have to use a different IDE for physical iOS testing compared to Android is a problem.

The fact it deploys fine to the iOs device from VS made me think it was something to do with provisioning profiles and the below error is a red herring, as I'd had a few of those trying to get this all working in the first place.
One thing I have noticed in the Projects Debug configuration is that the Provision Profile says `Unable to parse application identifier from Info.plist` I have no idea what that should be set to in the Info.plist to add it either.
The Signing Identity is set to `Developer (Automatic)` this is the same in VS, and the Provision Profile states `Automatic`, I'm assuming that is a default value when there is not a specific one define in the `Info.plist`?

As a side note, I can build an XCode app and deploy that to the iOS device without problem.

Any help here would be great, now onto the error:

> Failed to install application on device iPhone 14: warning HE0003:
> Could not load the framework 'DVTDeveloperModeHelper' (path:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework/DVTDeveloperModeHelper):
> not found. 2022-11-05 20:54:54.260 mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but
> did not find extension point with identifier
> Xcode.IDEDebugger.VariablesViewQuickLookProvider for extension
> Xcode.IDEDebugger.SpriteKitQuickLookProvider of plug-in
> com.apple.IDESpriteKitParticleEditor 2022-11-05 20:54:54.262
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.IDEDebugger.VariablesViewQuickLookProvider for
> extension Xcode.SpriteKit.GKStateMachineQuickLookProvider of plug-in
> com.apple.IDESpriteKitParticleEditor 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.WatchApplication
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOSSimulator.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Application of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Tool
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOSSimulator.ViewDescriber of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.IntentsService-AppExtension
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType for extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType.WatchOS.Bundle of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.WatchKit2-AppExtension
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice for extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice.WatchOS.BundleInfo of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOS.ViewDescriber of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Framework of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.ExtensionKitAppExtension
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.AppExtension of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOS.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.274
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.IDEiPhoneSupport.TargetEditor for extension
> Xcode.IDEiPhoneSupport.TargetEditor.WatchOS.Application of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUIFramework
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.Application
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.AppExtension
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.tvOSSimulator.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.ExtensionKitAppExtension
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType for extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType.appletvos.Bundle of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ATVSimulator.ViewDescriber of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DeviceIconProvider for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DeviceIconProvider.AppleTV of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ATV.ViewDescriber of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.tvOS.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for
> extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.XPC
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI 2022-11-05 20:54:54.275
> mlaunch[24141:507766] Requested but did not find extension point with
> identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice for extension
> Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice.appletvos.BundleTargetInfo
> of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI error MT1006: Could not
> install the application
> '/Users/jamesstuddart/Code/app.name-mobile/AppName.Mobile/bin/Debug/net6.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/appName.Mobile.app'
> on the device 'iPhone 14': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle
> returned: 0xe800801c.

Comment: You could use textedit to open info.plist file to see if there's something wrong, such as unwanted space.

Comment: And your Bundle identifier should match your provisioning file.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have validated the info.plist and the values are all correct, there are no invalid characters, and as I say it works in VS for Mac.
Where, or how do I check the bundle identifier value and what they should be, I've tried to do it but could find a definitive answer.

Comment: Did you use  automatic provisioning ?

Comment: Automatic is what is displayed by the VS for Mac, so I assume so.

Comment: Forgive me if i misunderstood. In your question, "The fact it deploys fine to the iOs device from VS", "VS" refer to "VS for mac"? And you cannot deploy on ios device using VS for windows. Does this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-7.0) help?

Comment: It deploys to the iOS device via VS for mac, but I can't get it to deploy to the iOS device from Rider. I'm doing most of the work in Rider.

Comment: VS for Windows builds but wont start the simulator

Comment: I've also found issues similar to yours. That seems something wrong with Bundle ID. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364376/jetbrains-rider-xamarin-ios-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain/60365340?noredirect=1#comment106856024_60365340)

Comment: Any idea what the bundle id should look like, as VS for mac shows a "friendly name" from what I can see?

Comment: If you have a paid Apple developer account, i recommend that to create a new provisioning file and retry it. If not, you could use [Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos). That means the bundle ID in your info.plist should be the same as that in Xcode as Xcode will only create a provisioning profile for an explicit App ID

Comment: I do have an Apple Developer account, so I'll have to look into that.

Comment: You could generate a new provisioning file with apple id the same as Bundle Identifier in the info.plist at Apple Developer Portal and have a try.